# Dropdown list set put selected value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down menu that will select a value that is stored in the database. Right now the code creates a dropdown with the first option selected. I have read through several tutorials, and tried to apply them, but I cannot get this working. I hope someone can help.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Up-to-Date</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="uptodate"/>
        <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
        <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Whole code :**

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include("../includes/connect.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
 if(isset($_POST['btnSlaOp'])) {
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $uitgeleend=$_POST['uitgeleend'];
  $nr=$_POST['nr'];
  $model=$_POST['model'];
  $serienummer=$_POST['serienummer'];
  $capaciteit=$_POST['capaciteit'];
  $uptodate=$_POST['uptodate'];
  $persoon=$_POST['persoon'];
  $datumuitgeleend=$_POST['datumuitgeleend'];
  $datumretour=$_POST['datumretour'];
  $opmerking=$_POST['opmerking'];
  $sql="UPDATE ipads SET uitgeleend='$uitgeleend', nr='$nr', model='$model', serienummer='$serienummer', capaciteit='$capaciteit', uptodate='$uptodate', persoon='$persoon', datumuitgeleend='$datumuitgeleend', datumretour='$datumretour', opmerking='$opmerking' WHERE id='$id'";
  $result=$db->query($sql);
  header("location:overzicht-ipads.php");
 } else if (isset($_POST['btnSlaOpInGs'])) {
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $uitgeleend=$_POST['uitgeleend'];
  $nr=$_POST['nr'];
  $model=$_POST['model'];
  $serienummer=$_POST['serienummer'];
  $capaciteit=$_POST['capaciteit'];
  $uptodate=$_POST['uptodate'];
  $persoon=$_POST['persoon'];
  $datumuitgeleend=$_POST['datumuitgeleend'];
  $datumretour=$_POST['datumretour'];
  $opmerking=$_POST['opmerking'];
  $sql  ="UPDATE ipads SET nr='$nr', model='$model', serienummer='$serienummer', capaciteit='$capaciteit', uptodate='$uptodate', persoon='$persoon', datumuitgeleend='$datumuitgeleend', datumretour='$datumretour', opmerking='$opmerking' WHERE id='$id'";
  $sql .="INSERT INTO geschiedenis (SELECT * FROM ipads WHERE id='$id')";
  $sql .="UPDATE ipads SET uitgeleend='Nee', persoon='', datumuitgeleend='', datumretour='', opmerking='' WHERE id='$id'";
  $result=mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql);
  header("location:overzicht-ipads.php");
 }
 if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $sql="SELECT id, uitgeleend, nr, model, serienummer, capaciteit, uptodate, persoon, datumuitgeleend, datumretour, opmerking FROM ipads WHERE id='$id'";
  $result=$db->query($sql);
  $rij=$result->fetch_assoc();
  $uitgeleend=$rij['uitgeleend'];
  $nr=$rij['nr'];
  $model=$rij['model'];
  $serienummer=$rij['serienummer'];
  $capaciteit=$rij['capaciteit'];
  $uptodate=$rij['uptodate'];
  $persoon=$rij['persoon'];
  $datumuitgeleend=$rij['datumuitgeleend'];
  $datumretour=$rij['datumretour'];
  $opmerking=$rij['opmerking'];
  
  include("../includes/get_header_wn.php");
?>
            <h1 class="page-title">Wijzigen</h1>
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="active">Leen iPad <?php echo $nr ?></li>
        </ul>

        </div>

<form id="gegevensForm" class="col-xs-4" form method="POST" action="overzicht-ipads-edit.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Uitgeleend</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uitgeleend" value="<?php echo $uitgeleend ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nr</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nr" value="<?php echo $nr ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Model</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="model" value="<?php echo $model ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Serienummer</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serienummer" value="<?php echo $serienummer ?>" />
    </div>
    
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Capaciteit</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="capaciteit" value="<?php echo $capaciteit ?>" />
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Up-to-Date</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="uptodate"/>
  <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
  <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
  </select>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Persoon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="persoon" value="<?php echo $persoon ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum uitgeleend</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datumuitgeleend" value="<?php echo $datumuitgeleend ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum retour</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" name="datumretour" value="<?php echo $datumretour ?>" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Opmerking</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="opmerking" /><?php echo $opmerking ?></textarea>
 </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="btnSlaOp" input type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Opslaan</button>
 
    <a href="overzicht-ipads.php"><input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Annuleer" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></a>
 
 <button class="btn btn-primary pull-middle" name="btnSlaOpInGs" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Opslaan & Archiveren</button>
 
    <?php
  include('../includes/get_footer.php');
 ?>
</form>

<?php
   }
   } else {
   header("location:overzicht-ipads.php");
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the value from the database? Once you've got the value you can just use `$('select.form-control').val(databaseValue);`

Comment: I'm still learning, I put the whole code above. How do I apply this in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php: `if($selectedVal == "yourVal") echo "selected";`

e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Up-to-Date</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="uptodate"/>
        <option value="Ja" <?php if($selectedVal == "Ja") echo "selected";?>>Ja</option>
        <option value="Nee" <?php if($selectedVal == "Nee") echo "selected";?>>Nee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**edit:** in your case, replace `$selectedVal` with `$uptodate`